# Sinatra - How to best move variable/parameter between pages

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a register page with the usual email,name,password ..which is validated in the server's submitted route/page. if it fails then I redirect back but I want to fill the values back in the register page..I can put the register form parameters in the session but it will stay there...is there a page memory(a smaller scope than session) just like session which will be just for the next page and then gone/ which is the best way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider just passing those parameters in query string? Also, what about ajax validation (so that user won't have to leave the page until data's valid)?

Comment: @ sergei -- Does redirect does a post or get ...I don't like the query string..since it is going to be having password..if it is post..then I can do some thing like that..if it is going to be post how am I going to sent the parameters..thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just render the registration page from the POST route like this:

```
post '/register' do
  @registration_data = params[:stuff] # store all your registration data
  if info_validates  # everything validates
    redirect './user_home'
  else  # something fails validation
    haml :register  # or erb or whatever your template engine is
  end
end
```

Then in your view, have it fill in `@registration_data` if it exists.

Also, you can clear session data with `session.clear`.

Comment: thanks ..have seen this register page back to register before going to the next page in past...thanks for reminding again.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax validation would be much easier.  You just register an onclick event to your form submit button that makes a call to a page that returns a json status code with the error information or 200 for OK.  If 200, then submit.

Comment: I have the ajax validation...still there are going to some validations / authorization on the server...in which case I would need to redirecting to next page..how do I move the variable ..I remember a page scope in jsp...does sinatra has something like that???  ...Anyways thanks for chipping in..